# get nearest 9 or 5 number to a value in vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am a beginner in vba, and I would like to write a function that takes in an integer, and returns a value that is the closest integer terminating in either 5 or 9 (in base 10): 
    `f(x:int)->y:int, such that the remainder of y/10 == 5|9`

For example, the following inputs would return:

```
f(1444) -> 1445
f(37)   -> 39
f(75)   -> 75
f(129)  -> 129
```

Comment: Being clear about the inputs and outputs of your function is good, but be sure to use clear language to indicate that is what you're doing. Sometimes formalized notation ( f(x)->int ) helps be clear. Note that what this question really requires is your attempt to do this yourself, so we can help point out where you went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a parameter that allows `Round()` to do this. You can use a simple algorithm picking up the number with the smallest difference with the input:

```
Function test(ByVal nb As Variant) As Integer

    nbDown = Left(nb, Len(nb) - 1) & 5
    nbUp = Left(nb, Len(nb) - 1) & 9

    If (Abs(nb - nbDown) <= Abs(nb - nbUp)) Then
        test = nbDown
    Else
        test = nbUp
    End If

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Function RoundToFiveOrNine(ByVal lngNumber As Long) As Long
'Written by Jesse Kropf, 5/21/2018
'
'Note: Technically we're rounding to the nearest 5 or 10,
'   and returning 9 rather than 10.
'
    Dim lngResult As Long
    Dim lngRemainder As Long

    'Round to nearest 5 first.
    lngResult = Round(lngNumber / 5) * 5

    'If number ends in 0, subtract 1.
    If Right(Str(lngResult), 1) = "0" Then lngResult = lngResult - 1

    RoundToFiveOrNine = lngResult

End Function
```